# Komodo IDE Ruby on Rails Editor auto-insert code issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, komodo

I've searched all over this site, and since I don't know what this particular function is called, I'm not sure how to find the answer, so apologies if this is a repeat.

I'm a new Ruby On Rails dev using Komodo IDE.  When I type something such as

def full_title

it auto-inserts a bunch of crap until the text looks like:

def fulll_title(args)
    #code
  end

How do I either get rid of the (args) and (#code) or make use of them?  Having to manually delete that junk is getting really, really old.  I'm fine with either solution as long as there IS a solution.  I don't even know what that particular feature is called, so I'm having a really hard time Googling/finding the answer on my own

Comment: If you want a Java based Ruby on Rails IDE. Get [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). Nothing comes close.

Comment: Not really looking for a new IDE, just how to make this one do something simple, but thanks!  I tried RubyMine and it doesn't seem capable of directly editing remote files, which I need

Answer (score 0):

Komodo IDE calls this feature [code intelligence](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.5/prefs.html#code_intel), and here are a few unrelated questions on controlling it:

- [Komodo Edit disable autocomple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666599/1113772)
- [Calltips/Docstring while viewing function list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439730/1113772)
- [Komodo Edit macro to replace a specific word in current document with clipboard content; is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421229/1113772)